# How can I use "My" in like @html.My.TextboxControl using Razor htmlhelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

My question is - how can I with code like this:

```
@Html.My.SelectControl(Sub(settings)
    settings.Id = "mySelect"

    settings.Items.Add(Sub(itm)
        itm.Value = "1"
        itm.Text = "First"
        itm.Selected = False
    End Sub)

    settings.Items.Add(Sub(itm)
        itm.Value = "2"
        itm.Text = "Second"
        itm.Selected = True
    End Sub)
End Sub).GetHtml()
```

... produce this result ...

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2" selected>second</option>
</select>
```

...?

I know how to use @html.MyTextboxControl, but I can't figure out how to "sub-class" it, so I can write code like this:

```
@html.My.TextboxControl(sub(settings) 
                       ' .settings. bla bla
                       ).GetHtml()

@html.My.ListboxControl(sub(settings) 
                       ' .settings. bla bla
                       ).GetHtml()
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The mechanism you are actually using when you extend the `HtmlHelper<TModel>` are [Extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

As the name suggests, these are **methods**, not classes, therefore you can't subclass.
The signature to add custom methods looks like this (C#, I am not familiar with VB):

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {
    public static MvcHtmlString MySelectControl<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Settings settings) {
            return new MvcHtmlString(/*....*/);
    }
}
```

I don't see the need for the `@Hmtl.My.Foo()` syntax. You can put all your custom extensions into a single static class, so they all can easily be kept together in your project. If you want to enforce a naming convention, just prefix the names of all your custom extension methods with "My" or whatever.